# Correct rewrite rule in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have a URL like `story/0/1517/s-l-u-g/`.In the .htaccess file, i have written the following rule to take it to the correct internal page.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^story/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/?$ story_detail.php?catid=$1&sid=$2 [NC]
```

The above rule is not working.When i click on it , it says '404 error, File Not Found'.I am using WAMP.

Please advise whether i am doing it correctly or not with an example.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your pattern seems to be a problem here.

Try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^story/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/ story_detail.php?catid=$1&sid=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

This will allow anything in slug to be passed.

Comment: SWEET!!.It works like a charm @anubhava.Thanks a lot and Happy Makar Sakarnti

Comment: One more question @abnubhava, in the above htaccess file i have numerous RewriteRules and one rule to handle 404 error.I have noticed that 404 error is generated but the designated 404.php page does not show.Why is it so?? ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Comment: I suggest opening a new question for this 404 issue and don't forget to place full .htaccess in new question